# Clear cart not working for guest user WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to clear WooCommerce cart using the following code,

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```

This is working fine if the user is logged in, But not working if the products added as a guest(not log in).why? Is it possible to clear the cart?